# Extract key vale from specific keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Suppose I have json as:

```
const details = {
    "something1":1,
    "something2":20,
    "something3":123,
    "something4":[{"a":"apple","b":"ball"},
    "something5":1211
}
```

for this I tried:

```
let final = {}

for (let keys in details) {
    // console.log(keys)
    if (keys == 'something1'|| 'something2'|| 'something3') {
        final[keys] = details[keys]
    }
}
```

But it's giving me the same result as **details**

Expected O/p should be ...

```
console.log(final) => {"something1":1,"something2":20,"something3":123}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a function with destructuring and get a new objects.

```js
const
    getParts = ({ something1, something2, something3 }) => ({ something1, something2, something3 }),
    details = { something1: 1, something2: 20, something3: 123, something4: [{ a: "apple", b: "ball" }], something5: 1211 },
    final = getParts(details);

console.log(final);
```

A dynamic approach

```js
const
    details = { something1: 1, something2: 20, something3: 123, something4: [{ a: "apple", b: "ball" }], something5: 1211 },
    wanted = ['something1', 'something2', 'something3'],
    final = Object.fromEntries(wanted.map(k => [k, details[k]]));

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `filter()` the entries of the object and then convert it back to object using `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const details = {
    "something1":1,
    "something2":20,
    "something3":123,
    "something4":[{"a":"apple","b":"ball"}],
    "something5":1211
}

const removeProps = (obj, props) => (
     Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, _]) => !props.includes(k)))
)

const res = removeProps(details, ['something1', 'something2']);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is with `keys === 'something1'|| 'something2'|| 'something3'`:

```js
const details = {
    "something1":1,
    "something2":20,
    "something3":123,
    "something4":[{"a":"apple","b":"ball"}],
    "something5":1211,
    }
    
let final = {}

for (let keys in details) {
    // console.log(keys)
    if (keys === 'something1'|| keys === 'something2'|| keys==='something3') {
        final[keys] = details[keys]
    }
}

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are already good answers that show how to solve the issue, but they don't explain why your code does not work.

The reason is that you misunderstood what this boolean condition does:

```
keys == 'something1'|| 'something2'|| 'something3')
```

It does **not** mean: *key is any of*.
It does mean:

1. if `keys == 'something1'`
2. OR if `'something2'`
3. OR if `'something3'`

Your 2nd and 3rd or-expressions are just plain strings.
And any non-blank string evaluates to boolean `true`.

```js
// non-empty strings are boolean TRUE
console.log(`Boolean: 'something2'`, Boolean('something2'));
// empty strings are boolean FALSE
console.log(`Boolean: ''`, Boolean(''));
```

So your 2nd and 3rd OR conditions are always `true` and thus the whole condition is `true`.

So if you want to stick to the explicit comparison, then use this:

```
if (keys === 'something1'|| keys === 'something2'|| keys==='something3') {
```

BTW: you may want to use `===` instead of `==`: see [Javascript === (triple equals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112934/javascript-triple-equals)

Comment: Thank you for taking you time and providing proper explanation. :)